# How to fix the fonts in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

[image]

[image]

It has only stated today after installing KDE's system settings and configuring it to make KDE apps look native . Firefox has started using a thinner font.

so how do i make it use the default fonts ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is font hinting.

First, play with the font rendering settings in KDE and see if it fixes your problem.

You can probably disable it in `about:config` by searching for the preferences starting with "gfx" and testing them out.