# PDFs don't render correctly with Firefox and pdf.js

Tags: firefox, fonts, ipv6, firefox-extensions

While using Firefox on Windows, pdf.js worked beautifully. It was honestly amazing. But on (K)ubuntu, it fails to render the files - not just some, but any (which is why I'm posting here). For example, I searched for 'pdf' on Google and opened [the first pdf file](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf), and it looked like this:

[image: Yikes]

[image]

All pdfs look like this, some even worse. Has anyone else had this problem? I found a few posts about terrible font rendering with pdf.js, but all those posters said it had been resolved with an update ... I have already tried disabling all addons, reinstalling Firefox (I even reinstalled Kubuntu (not because of this problem)).

Comment: Can you explain the problem in the screenshot? It looks fine to me since I don't know what problems I should be looking for.

Comment: The font rendering is horrible, as if it has uneven kerning. Many symbols are gibberish, as if there was some error while converting it. I've uploaded a clearer picture

Comment: The second part is probably another question altogether. IMO

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Done.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this on?

Comment: @fluteflute 12.04 and 12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on Firefox 16 on Kubuntu 12.10 .. Fixed! There were two things I did to fix it:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
sudo rm 10-*.conf
```

and by following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49044/how-to-fix-the-fonts-in-firefox?rq=1)

Comment: I think, your answer will go from good to excellent if you include more info here. ;)

Comment: What else should I add?

Answer (score 2):

I use the development version of pdf.js, and the PDF you linked to displays as expected on my system.

Try [installing the development version of pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/extensions/firefox/pdf.js.xpi) and see if this helps.

> The development extension should be quite stable but still might break
>   from time to time. Also, note that the development extension is
>   updated on every merge and by default Firefox will auto-update
>   extensions on a daily basis (you can change this through the
>   extensions.update.interval option in about:config).

Comment: Nope, no difference :(

Comment: @asymptotically In order to "reproduce" my setup, perhaps try the official [Firefox beta PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next)